# React Native iOS: Check notifications perms memory leak, how to check notifications perms on app launch?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, push-notification, permissions

I want to be able to check if the user has notification permissions on or off every time the user opens the app from any state ( if the app was never opened before or the app was in the background etc.) What I have now is checking permissions via PushNotificationIOS.checkPermissions in the render function. However, with that method it keeps on being called and causes a memory leak. Another method I tried was whenever the user wants to be notified (via pressing an icon) the onPress method is called to check the perms but that causes the user to press the icon twice in order for the permission state to be updated.

```
import {
    PushNotificationIOS,
    AsyncStorage,
    ..
  } from "react-native";


export default class Bell extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);  
    this.state = {
      isNotifActive: null,
      isBellActive: false,
      alertBody:"",
      fireDate: null,
      LaunchStatus: "",
      ID:'',
      timeSelected: ""
    };
    this.accessKeyNotif = `${this.props.fireDate}-isNotifActive`;

  }

  componentDidMount = () =>{
    this.setState({
        set props to state....
    });
    AsyncStorage.getItem(this.accessKeyNotif).then(value => this.setState({ isNotifActive: JSON.parse(value) }));

  }

  render() {
    PushNotificationIOS.checkPermissions((permissions) => {
      if (permissions.alert) {
        AsyncStorage.setItem(this.accessKeyNotif, JSON.stringify(true)).then(() => {
          this.setState({ isNotifActive: true});

        });
      }
      else{
        AsyncStorage.setItem(this.accessKeyNotif, JSON.stringify(false)).then(() => {
          this.setState({ isNotifActive: false});

        });
      }
    }); 

     return (
      <Ionicons
        name={this.state.isBellActive? "md-notifications":"md-notifications-off"}
        color={"white"}
        size={30}
        style={styles.NotifIcon}
        onPress={() => {
            if(this.state.isNotifActive){
             Make a notification
            }
            else if(!this.state.isNotifActive){
               Cancel Notifications
              }
            }}
        />

    );
  }  
}
```

The Bell component is called on multiple times (20 times) by another class in order to display the bell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be performing that check in the `render` method as each `setState` will cause a re-render, meaning to multiple unnecessary re-renders. It would be better handling this using an `AppState` listener. The following code will call `_handleAppStateChange` whenever the app comes into the foreground, goes into the background.

You can import it from react-native like so

```
import { AppState } from 'react-native'
```

Then in your component

```
state = {
  appState: AppState.currentState,  // set the currentState as the appState
};


componentDidMount () {
  // Set the listener
  AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
}

componentWillUnmount () {
  // remove the listener
  AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
}

_handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
  if (this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active') {
    // app has come to the foreground
    // perform checks etc here
  }
  // update the appState
  this.setState({ appState: nextAppState });
}
```

You can read more about it here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate

Comment: To better understand this code. `this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active'` , checks to see the previous appState (for instance it was in the background) and also checks if the current state is active via the `handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState)` ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I actually lifted this code from an app that I built. I use it to perform updates when the app comes to the foreground